# How can I pull in all data in the input_data without explicitly entering them manually one-by-one

Tags: zapier

I am connecting ZingTree to Zapier. Zingtree provides many data variables to Zapier. Instead of manually entering them all and maintaining at two places, is it possible for Zapier to populate input_data dictionary with all variables from the app step?
Thanks!